# How to save R plot in different directories in terminal/shell?

Tags: r, shell, terminal

Suppose I have a r script named "plot.R" such that:

```
uva<-commandArgs(T)
file1<-as.character(uva[1])
x<-read.table(file1,header=T)
png("plot.png")
boxplot(x)
dev.off()
q()
```

And then I run this plot.R in a for-loop in Shell,

```
for i in AA  ALA 
    do
    R --args $i  <plot.R
done
```

This will save the plot in the current directory. My question is how to save each plot-i into each sub-directories. I have tried something like `R --args $i  <plot.R | mv *png dir`, but it does not work. Does anybody know how to realize that?

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your R code to save your plots based on command line arguments and feed that into your png call rather than trying to do that from the command line.  Just use the argument to construct the path for png.